# Efficiently get selected option in a drop-down list (XHTML Select element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

**Background**

There's a large list of options - dozens - in a drop-down list using an XHTML Select element.

Using JavaScript, I need to retrieve the selected option.

**Problem**

Currently I'm using jQuery `:selected` CSS selector and it works as expected, but this approach isn't efficient as it takes a while to find selected option - obviously, it depends on CPU power of client machine, but in a decent Intel Core 2 with 4GB of RAM, there's an excesive performance penalty.

**Issue**

Either using jQuery or plain JavaScript and DOM, I need to get selected option of this XHTML Select element in an efficient way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Should be as easy as:

```
// assuming `select` refers to the select DOM element
var selectedElement = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
```

See [HTMLSelectElement *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement).

**Update:**

In newer browsers which support the following methods (they are part of **HTML5**), you could also use:

```
var selectedElement = select.item(select.selectedIndex);
// or
var selectedElement = select[select.selectedIndex];
// or
var selectedElement = select.selectedOptions[0];
```

Comment: N.B. `select` is **not** a jQuery in this case.

Comment: Sure, and it's for all: maybe I'm asleep, because how stupid is the solution for that and I obviously I knew that haha, anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Matías: :) No worries, that happens to all of us I guess :D You're welcome :)

Comment: Thank you again, anyway I'm laughting because I've asked such stupid question...! It's just because I was thinking in "jQuery only" approaches...

Comment: if you just need the value then  use `var selectedValue = select.value;`

Answer (score 3):

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById("yourId");
dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ["vanilla" DOM `selectedIndex` property of the `<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement#Properties).

```
var $select = $('#mySelect'),
    si = $select.get(0).selectedIndex,
    $selectedOpt = $select.children('option:eq(' + si + ')');
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't thought about using `selectedIndex`. I'm going to try this and probably your answer will be the right one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="sel">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
</select>

$("#sel").val()
```

Comment: Getting the value is not the same as getting the element. This *might* be what the OP wants but I'd assume he knows about `val`.

Comment: He's trying to get the element not the value of the selected index.

Comment: As @FelixKling said, if you need to get the option, because of some "data" or other reason, getting the value will not achieve the task