# How do I create an array from a list

Tags: javascript, arrays

So basically I have made an array and a function that shows the array in a list in my HTML. Now I want to create a new array made out of the chosen ones in the list.

My array:

```
var fighters = [
  {
     "name": "Abdi",
     "HP": 100,
     "DMG": 20
  },
  {
     "name": "chriz",
     "HP": 100,
     "DMG": 40
  },
  {
     "name": "Erik",
     "HP": 120,
     "DMG": 11
  }
];
```

The 2 lists made out of my array.

```
for (var fighter of fighters) listX.innerHTML += `<option value="${fighter.name}">${fighter.name}</option>` ;
for (var fighter of fighters) listY.innerHTML += `<option value="${fighter.name}">${fighter.name}</option>` ;
```

I basically want a new array called `chosen` made out of the options I chose in the 2 lists I have, so I can later use it in `myFunction()` code/function.

the rest of my code :

```
function choose() {
  var playerX = document.getElementById('listX').value;
  document.getElementById('FighterX').innerHTML = "you selected " + playerX;

  var playerY = document.getElementById('listY').value;
  document.getElementById('FighterY').innerHTML = "you selected " + playerY;
}

function myFunction() {

  while (chosen[0].HP > 0 && chosen[1].HP > 0) {
    chosen[1].HP -= chosen[0].HP;
    chosen[0].HP -= chosen.DMG;
    document.getElementById('resultX').innerHTML += chosen.HP;
    document.getElementById('resultY').innerHTML += chosen.HP;
  }
}
```

Comment: What should this array look like?

Comment: something along the lines of the fighter i chose in the lists with their HP and DMG

Comment: Start with this to get the names of the selected fighters: [Efficiently get selected option in a drop-down list (XHTML Select element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956963/efficiently-get-selected-option-in-a-drop-down-list-xhtml-select-element). Then use `filter()` on your list.

Comment: If you set `value` on each `<option>` to the index in the list instead of the name of the fighter, it will be even easier to get the selected ones with `map()` instead of `filter()`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice why are you putting an answer in comments?

Comment: @råby just submitted my solution. I wasn't clear on a few details about how `myFunction` should work and what the end result should be, so feel free to comment feedback on my solution if you'd like for me to adjust my logic. Thanks!

Comment: @machineghost feel free to copy those comments and put them in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't exactly sure about a few different aspects of your program, since you seem to be calling `chosen` without indexes near the end, and I also adjusted the logic at the end to parse the values as integers when performing your mathematic functions. Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

```js
const listX = document.getElementById('listX');
const listY = document.getElementById('listY');

const fighters = [
  {
    name: "Abdi",
    HP: 100,
    DMG: 20
  }, {
    name: "Chriz",
    HP: 100,
    DMG: 40
  }, {
    name: "Erik",
    HP: 120,
    DMG: 11
  }
];

for (let fighter of fighters) listX.innerHTML += `<option value="${fighter.name}">${fighter.name}</option>`;
for (let fighter of fighters) listY.innerHTML += `<option value="${fighter.name}">${fighter.name}</option>`;

const chosen = Array(2).fill();

function choose() {
  const playerX = document.getElementById('listX').value;
  document.getElementById('FighterX').innerHTML = "you selected " + playerX;
  chosen[0] = fighters.find(fighter => fighter.name === playerX);
  const playerY = document.getElementById('listY').value;
  document.getElementById('FighterY').innerHTML = "you selected " + playerY;
  chosen[1] = fighters.find(fighter => fighter.name === playerY);
}
choose();
document.addEventListener('change', e => e.target?.matches('select') && ['listX','listY'].includes(e.target.id) && choose());

function myFunction() {
  const chosenPlayers = chosen.map(fighter => ({ ...fighter }));
  document.getElementById('resultX').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('resultY').innerHTML = '';
  while (chosenPlayers[0].HP > 0 && chosenPlayers[1].HP > 0) {
    chosenPlayers[1].HP -= chosenPlayers[0].HP;
    chosenPlayers[0].HP -= chosenPlayers[1].DMG;
    document.getElementById('resultX').innerHTML = (parseInt(document.getElementById('resultX').innerHTML) || 0) + chosenPlayers[0].HP;
    document.getElementById('resultY').innerHTML = (parseInt(document.getElementById('resultY').innerHTML) || 0) + chosenPlayers[1].HP;
  }
}
```

```html
<strong>List X</strong>
<select id="listX"></select>
<div id="FighterX"></div>
<div id="resultX"></div>
<strong>List Y</strong>
<select id="listY"></select>
<div id="FighterY"></div>
<div id="resultY"></div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Run simulation</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother this should be it but I really need help understanding the lines from const choose untill `document.addEventListener('change', e => e.target?.matches('select') && ['listX','listY'].includes(e.target.id) && choose());

Comment: Sure @råby, I'd be happy to explain any specific questions you have! You can also join me to chat about it here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231654/stackoverflow-question-67274002

Answer (score 0):

First, you can combine your options appending into one loop.

Here is a working example. It uses an event listener for each select as well as uses filter for searching the fighters by name

```js
let listX = document.querySelector(".listX");
let listY = document.querySelector(".listY");
let FighterX = document.querySelector(".FighterX");
let FighterY = document.querySelector(".FighterY");
let chosen = []
let fighters = [{
    "name": "Abdi",
    "HP": 100,
    "DMG": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "chriz",
    "HP": 100,
    "DMG": 40
  },
  {
    "name": "Erik",
    "HP": 120,
    "DMG": 11
  }
];

    for (var fighter of fighters) {
        listX.innerHTML += `<option value="${fighter.name}">${fighter.name}</option>` ;
        listY.innerHTML += `<option value="${fighter.name}">${fighter.name}</option>` ;
    }

function choose(name) {
  return fighters.filter(function(a, b) {
    return (a.name.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase())
  })[0];
}

listX.addEventListener("change",function(){
  if(this.value != "") chosen[0] = choose(this.value)
  FighterX.innerHTML = this.value + " has been chosen";
});

listY.addEventListener("change",function(){
  if(this.value != "") chosen[1] = choose(this.value)
  FighterY.innerHTML = this.value + " has been chosen";
});
```

```html
<select class="listX">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

<select class="listY">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

<div class="FighterX"></div>
<div class="FighterY"></div>
```